# Python Pandas if column contains a certain int

Tags: python, pandas

I want to limit my output like I did with the .str.contains() but this time with an int. How do I make this code work with (normal) Python using Pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'yearweek' : [201604, 201604, 201604, 201604, 201605, 201605, 201605, 201605, 201606, 201606, 201606],
        'manufacturer' : ['F', 'F', 'S', 'S', 'F', 'F', 'S', 'S', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
        'reprint_reason_id' : [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
        'tot_volume' : [100, 150, 80, 90, 120, 98, 77, 250, 33, 110, 56]})

    df1 = df.groupby(by=['yearweek', 'manufacturer']) ['tot_volume'].sum()
    df2 = df1.reset_index()
    df3 = df2[df2['manufacturer'].str.contains('F') ]
    df4 = df3.reset_index()
    df5 = df4[df4['yearweek'].int.contains(201604)]
    print df5
```

Comment: What is the expected output what are you trying to achive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'yearweek' : [201604, 201604, 201604, 201604, 201605, 201605, 201605, 201605, 201606, 201606, 201606],
        'manufacturer' : ['F', 'F', 'S', 'S', 'F', 'F', 'S', 'S', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
        'reprint_reason_id' : [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
        'tot_volume' : [100, 150, 80, 90, 120, 98, 77, 250, 33, 110, 56]})

#convert to int is not necessary in this sample
#df['yearweek'] = df['yearweek'].astype(int)

df1 = df.groupby(by=['yearweek', 'manufacturer'])['tot_volume'].sum().reset_index()
#or you can use
#df1 = df.groupby(by=['yearweek', 'manufacturer'], as_index=False)['tot_volume'].sum()
print df1
   yearweek manufacturer  tot_volume
0    201604            F         250
1    201604            S         170
2    201605            F         218
3    201605            S         327
4    201606            F          33
5    201606            S         166

print (df1['manufacturer'].str.contains('F')) & (df1['yearweek'] == 201604)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool

df2 = df1[(df1['manufacturer'].str.contains('F')) & (df1['yearweek'] == 201604)]
print df2
   yearweek manufacturer  tot_volume
0    201604            F         250
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this line to solve my problem to check the content in a column DataFrame.
It converts the Data column to Strings and then checks the content

```
df2 = df1[df1['yearweek'].astype('str').str.contains('201604')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.astype(int)` to convert that to `integer`. Like this `df4[df4['yearweek'].astype(int).contains(201604)]`